# where is sscanf_s?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-6

sscanf_s is undefined on my system.  The definition is not included in any of the stdio.h files I have from various SDKs.  I searched all files on my system for this.

I have microsoft visual c++ 6.0

what is the proper .h file and library and where do I get them?

Comment: It seems that in this case, this function is simply unimplemented (thus not available) on the platform you're targeting.

Comment: `sscanf_s()` is a Microsoft only function.

Comment: This is a non-standard function, so I would expect it *not* to be on your platform without further information.

Comment: i have microsoft visual c++ 6.0

Comment: a) use iostreams, b) don't use a 14 years old compiler that does not even implement C++1998.

Comment: Right now it is a standard function, defined in C11 (ISO/IEC 9899:201x, "K.3.5.3.7 The sscanf_s function"), but not for C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sscanf_s()` is a Microsoft only function, and, based on [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), was introducted in VS 2005 so is not available in VS 6.0.

Either use `sscanf()` or upgrade your compiler.